# Storing the values of an array for future refernce

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, storage

I have an **Arraylist**, the values of which keep changing. These values should be saved because the next time the application opens, the previous values have to be there.Right now I just save it in an list but the next time the values are not saved. How can I store the values?

Comment: Store in SharedPreference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store it in a file or a database table.

And read it next time when you open the application.